# ¿ Como puedo hacer para que la regex pare en el primer match?

Tags: python, regex

¿Como puedo hacer para que la regex devuelva únicamente hasta el primer parentesis?

El string original es:

```
Carrollton, asd (University of West Georgia)[2]*Dahlonega (North Georgia College & State University)[2]
```

Cuando ejecuto la siguiente regex:

```
(.+)\s(
```

obtengo:

```
Carrollton, asd (University of West Georgia)[2]*Dahlonega
```

y lo que necesito es:

```
Carrollton, asd
```

La linea de codigo completa que estoy utilizando para extraer es:

```
df2['RegionName'].str.extract(r'(.+)\s\(')
```

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

//////////////////

Edición:

Necesito que el regex al pasarle:

```
Carrollton, asd (University of West Georgia)[2]*Dahlonega (North Georgia College & State University)[2]
```

me devuelva:

```
Carrollton, asd
```

y al pasarle el string:

```
The Five College Region of Western Massachusetts:
```

lo devuelva sin modificaciones.

En resumen, que el regex solo elimine todo aquello que hay después del primer parentesis, si lo hay. Las soluciones propuestas hasta ahora (por mala exposición de mi pregunta incial) funcionan bien con el primer string, pero con el segundo devuelven:

```
NaN
```

o

```
The Five College Region of Western
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
^([^(]+)(?:$|\s)
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/46eR27/2/).

Si no necesitas el espacio final, entonces utiliza el valor que hay en el primer grupo de captura.

La idea es capturar cualquier caracter que no sea paréntesis. Así terminará en el primer paréntesis y no avanzará hasta el segundo.

Por otro lado, la expresión debe terminar en espacio o en fin de línea. El fin de línea es para que la expresión regular pueda 'consumir' caracteres hasta el final (si no tuviera un espacio al final de la frase)

Answer (score 1):

Al margen de que falta un `\` delante del paréntesis final, es decir, tu expresión debería ser:

```
(.+)\s\(
```

lo que está ocurriendo es que el grupo `(.+)` es *greedy* (glotón) y se "come" todo lo que puede. Ya que el `.` representa "cualquier carácter", eso incluye también el espacio y el paréntesis, y por tanto se los "come" también. Así, sobre la cadena:

```
Carrollton, asd (University of West Georgia)[2]*Dahlonega (North Georgia College & State University)[2]
```

se "comerá" todo lo que pueda hasta que encuentre un espacio seguido de paréntesis que ya no pueda comerse porque no aparece otro espacio+paréntesis después. En otras palabras, encaja todo hasta el *último* espacio seguido de paréntesis en la cadena.

La solución es hacer que el grupo sea *non-greedy*, lo que se logra poniendo un `?` tras el carácter re repetición (en este caso el `+`). Es decir, la expresión que buscas sería:

```
(.+?)\s\(
```

De ese modo el grupo de captura se detendrá ante el primer espacio seguido de paréntesis.

[Demo aqui](https://regex101.com/r/Ghmydg/1)

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción es la de usar l expresión `palabra1(?=palabra2)` que busca "palabra1" si es precedida por "palabra2"

Entonces, tu código quedaría por el estilo.

```
import re

cadena = 'Carrollton, asd (University of West Georgia)[2]*Dahlonega (North Georgia College & State University)[2]' 
patt = r'.*?(?=\()'  #  Haciendo la busqueda non-greedy, evitando que 
                     #+ empareje todo lo que pueda, buscando todo lo que
                     #+ este antes del primer parentesis.

res = re.search(patt, cadena)
print(res.group(0))
```